# Select Multiple feature using select interaction

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

How to select multiple feature using select interaction in openlayers 3?Is it possible. Multiple feature can be selected using drag-box. But I have needed using select interaction.

Comment: I don't know the precise coding in OpenLayers 3, but couldn't you add a button trigger to draw a box (OL3 probably has a drawing mode), take the shape of the box and then find features either within or intersecting that shape from the layer you want to get features from?  I do it that way in ESRI and other SW packages.  It should work for OL3.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about to select with dragbox. 
But you can select multiple features using select interaction.

First select any of feature and then keep press shift and select other features.

So, this way you can select multiple features in ol3.

Answer (score 1):

From OpenLayers 3 docs : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html

> multi     boolean | undefined     experimental
>   A boolean that determines if the default behaviour should select only single features or all (overlapping) features at the clicked map position. Default is false i.e single select